# setText() on TextView, not working in my code

Tags: android, if-statement, settext

I am making an app. When I try to setText on my TextView it does not work!

scoreteam_a and scoreteam_b does not setText().
The if statements do not work too. please help me. What's wrong in my code?
teama and teamb setText() method works but not on scoreteam_a and scoreteam_b.
I directly access variables from activity in the methods.

Here's my code :

```
package com.example.android.courtcounter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FinishActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Bundle bundle;
String teama_name;
String teamb_name;
int scoreteama;
int scoreteamb;
String scoreTeamAString;
String scoreTeamBString;
private TextView winnera;
private TextView winnerb;
private TextView draw;
private TextView teama;
private TextView teamb;
private TextView scoreteam_a;
private TextView scoreteam_b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish);



    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    winnera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnera);
    winnerb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winnerb);
    draw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.draw);
    teama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teama);
    teamb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teamb);
    scoreteam_a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreteama);
    scoreteam_b = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scoreteamb);

    teama_name = MainActivity.teamAName;
    teamb_name = MainActivity.teamBName;
    scoreteama = ScoringActivity.scoreTeamA;
    scoreteamb = ScoringActivity.scoreTeamB;
    scoreTeamAString = ScoringActivity.stringTeamA;
    scoreTeamBString = ScoringActivity.stringTeamB;

    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the blinking time with this parameter
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

    if (scoreteama > scoreteamb) {
        winnera.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        winnera.startAnimation(anim);
    } else if (scoreteamb > scoreteama) {
        winnerb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        winnerb.startAnimation(anim);
    } else if (scoreteamb == scoreteama) {
        draw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        draw.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    teama.setText(teama_name);
    teamb.setText(teamb_name);
    scoreteam_a.setText(ScoringActivity.stringTeamA);
    scoreteam_b.setText(ScoringActivity.stringTeamB);



    TextView shareButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
    shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, teama_name + " vs " + teamb_name + "\n" + teama_name + " = " + scoreteama + "\n" + teamb_name + " = " + scoreteamb);
            startActivity(shareIntent);
        }
    });
}

public void newmatch(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FinishActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    winnera.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    winnerb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    draw.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    winnera.clearAnimation();
    winnerb.clearAnimation();
    draw.clearAnimation();
   }
   }
```

Comment: You should never do that. To pass data from activity to another activity you should use Intents or startForResult and set result. there are a lot of different ways to accomplish that (RxJava, EventBus, ContentProvider...)

Comment: Why is that bundle not used? Why created then? Why putting values from other activity to this activity's string variables and still using those values from other activity to set text instead of newly created local variables? Why so many public static declared variables in ScoringActivity when you can use that bundle?

Comment: Why don;t you print the `ScoringActivity.scoreTeamA`, `ScoringActivity.scoreTeamB` and `ScoringActivity.stringTeamA` and `ScoringActivity.stringTeamB` variables prior setting them to the textviews to see if they contain the results you are expecting? Just use `Log.d("TAG", "ScoringActivity.stringTeamA: " + ScoringActivity.stringTeamA);`. I guess you won't get the expected results. The practice you use to get the results from another activity by static reference is wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not set integer to Texview.

try to use `textview.setText(String.valueOf(scoreteama))`

Comment: he is trying to set text to others activity textview which is complete nonsense

Comment: I don't know what he is doing in other activity, and he did not give any in the code. So the problem is most likely seems for that reason.

Comment: Viktor I am not trying to set text to other activity textView rather I am accessing variable from another activity.

Comment: But what about the if statements?

Comment: Can;t see in question's code where he is setting `setText(scoreteama)`, I only see `scoreteam_a.setText(ScoringActivity.stringTeamA);` and `scoreteam_b.setText(ScoringActivity.stringTeamB);` How did you know these variables were `int`s and not `String`s as their name implies?

Comment: Activity could be killed at any time point and that is why you should not refer from one activity's static field to another, this can cause memory leaks as well!

Comment: @Pleft that the reason even I mentioned earlier and  even I can't understand how can this be the answer by provided code.

Comment: Ok, According to the current issue, 2 problems occured in my mind at first. One of them is score is null (in this case it obviously converted from int which looks like impossible) and second of them is there is an error while converting int to string. This is why I suggested that solution. I dont know what is going on in the other activity or the current one.